# Difference between Primary key and Candidate key

Tags: sql, key, rdbms

I have read about Keys in RDBMS. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6951124/1647112
I however couldn't understand the need to use a candidate key. If a primary key is all that is needed to uniquely identify a row in a table, why is candidate key required? 
Please give a good example as to state the differences and importance of various keys.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the OP wants this: Suppose you have three tables. Your main table has as its primary the most important (to the data design) key defined as a primary key. But. The other 2 tables have different primary keys.  In order to make effieicent joins between table 1 and 2 or table 1 and 3, you may need to add the common column from the foreign table - a foreign key - to table 1.  This is another way of looking at what you are trying to understand.  Foreign keys the uniquely idnetify rows in rable 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A table can have one or more candidate keys - these are keys that uniquely identify a row in the table.

However, only one of these candidate keys can be chosen to be the primary key.

Comment: @ShashankRaghunath - Yes. The one you selected.

Comment: Please be kind enough to tell me, why are super keys used?

Comment: @ShashankRaghunath - Where exactly do you see them used? It is just a term, as far as I know, without much practical use.

Comment: Havent seen them anywhere.I have to learn them for my exams. I simply cant get my head around these keys.

Comment: You can have more than one columns as a PK? Can't you?

Comment: @rohan-patel - a **candidate-key** can be more than one field. It follows that so can the chosen PK.

Answer (score 0):

From, the above answer i came to this conclusion

Super key(one or more attributes used for selecting one or more rows)

```
                        ||
                        \/
```

Candidate key(one or more attributes from super used for selecting a single row)

```
                        ||  
                        \/
```

Primary key(one attribute among candidate keys used for selecting a single row)

Am i correct?

Comment: The **primary key** is **one of the candidate keys**, picked by you as the database designer. It's not *part* of a candidate key - it's **one of the existing, identified** candidate keys (the **whole** candidate key).