# Compound key/ Composite Key / Concatenated Key / Aggregate Key / Candidate Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can anyone please give me a clear idea of the difference of these keys?

1. Compound key
2. Composite Key
3. Concatenated Key
4. Aggregate Key
5. Candidate Key

I searched for the definitions of all these and it seems some of them are just synonyms. But not sure if I understood then correctly. I would be thankful if someone can come up with a descriptive answer comparing the differences and similarities.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Key, Superkey, Minimal Superkey, Candidate Key, Primary Key DIFFERENCES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951052/key-superkey-minimal-superkey-candidate-key-primary-key-differences)

Comment: @Lion sir, there is no mention about Compound key, Composite Key, Concatenated Key and Aggregate Key.

Comment: I'm not sure about compound key but composite key and concatenate(d) key refer to the same. It is candidate key. It is also mentioned there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relational database terms there is only one fundamental type of key: a *candidate key*.

A candidate key is a set of attributes that is irreducibly unique and non-nullable within a table. *Irreducible* means that all the attributes of the key are necessary to guarantee uniqueness - remove any one attribute and the uniqueness property would be lost. A key may consist of zero, one or more attributes and a relational table (relation variable) must have at least one key and may have more than one.

*Compound*, *composite*, *concatenated* and *aggregate* are all alternative terms used to describe candidate keys with more than one attribute. A candidate key with exactly one attribute is called a *simple* key

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key Sir, in this wiki article there says Compound key is often confused with composite key. This made me to ask this question in SO . Are they really alternative terms?

Comment: In Relational terms they are the same thing; in Entity-Relationship Modelling they are subtly different. See: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/in-sql-is-it-composite-or-compound-keys

Comment: It is odd that this got closed for "Off Topic"! Either way - this is an incomplete answer because a composite key is one that can contain non simple key fields. A compound key contains only simple key fields.