# Can I use the same foreign key constraint in two different tables?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to create a database for work. I have two different types of users: internal and external. Each type has different properties so I just created two separate tables for them. In my internal table I have the following fields:

```
f_name VARCHAR(32),
l_name VARCHAR(32),
empl_status_id INT,
admin_grp_id INT,
reliab_status_id INT,
supv_id INT
```

And my external table has the following:

```
f_name VARCHAR(32),
l_name VARCHAR(32),
email VARCHAR(32),
phone VARCHAR(20),
org_id INT,
supv_id INT
```

I realize that I could probably create a separate table that contains the names of the users and a foreign key pointing to either internal or external, but that aside, I added a foreign key constraint to my internal table that refers `supv_id` to another internal user. I called it `fk_supv_id`. When I tried to do the same for my external user table, I got `ERROR 1005 (HY000)`.

At first I couldn't figure out what the problem was but when I tried doing it with a different name, it worked (i.e. instead of calling it `fk_supv_id` just like for internal, I called it `fk_xtsupv_id`).

So my question is, what is the correct way to this? It's the same foreign key in two different tables. In both cases it refers to an internal user. Is there a way to do this without having two different names? Or should I opt for the table of names idea and add the `supv_id` constraint to that table along with `f_name`, `l_name`, and `user_type`?

Advice and suggestions are appreciated,

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are columns and there are foreign keys (FKs) and there are constraints.

You can have a column name in a table regardless of other tables.

A FK is a referencing table and column set and a referenced table and column set. All the names together identify a FK. It's a conceptual thing about a database.

A FK constraint, being a constraint, is a thing whose name must be unique over the database. It has and enforces an associated FK, namely the one described in its declaration. You can have multiple FK constraints in a table enforcing the same FK.

The DBMS has automatic unique names for FK constraints. Eg a name part plus a number part where the constraint is the numberth FK constraint of the table with that name. You can actually have the same nameless FK constraint definition text multiple times in a table and in multiple tables, each for a different FK constraint. (The ones inside a given table enforce the same FK.)

You should have a unique naming scheme for when you want to name them. Referencing and referenced table names should be involved, and when necessary distinguishing column names.

Confusingly, we say FK when we mean FK constraint.

When you say "It's the same foreign key in two different tables," that misuses terms. There are two different FKs involved, and corresponding FK constraints. You mean maybe "it's the same referencing columns and referenced table and columns in both FK constraints" or "it's the same text re referencing in both table declarations' FK constraint declarations". But the FK constraint names must be unique.

When you say "In both cases it refers to an internal user," you are confirming that the type and/or table of the referenced column are the same for both FK constraints. But they are different FK constraints for different FKs.

Answer (score 3):

Names of FKs have to be unique.  You need to use two different FK names.  I would further suggest that you should include information about the tables being linked in the key name to make it more descriptive.

Comment: No, FK names have to be unique, period. Also, a FK is not a key so it's confusing to use "key" as shorthand for FK.

Comment: @philipxy - I updated for further clarity since FK is more specific, but a foreign key is by definition a kind of key.  It isn't a primary key, it isn't a unique key, but it is a key.  A key is a value that is a shortcut to accessing data and an FK is such a device.

Comment: No, it just has the word "key" in its name. A key is a specific different thing and a FK is not one. French toast is not toast. (A superkey is a set of columns that is unique. A key is a superkey that contains no smaller superkey. In SQL PK/KEY/UNIQUE all define superkeys, usually ones that are keys.)

Comment: @philipxy - From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951052/key-superkey-minimal-superkey-candidate-key-primary-key-differences - Key is a single or combination of multiple fields. Its purpose is to access or retrieve data rows from table according to the requirement. The keys are defined in tables to access or sequence the stored data quickly and smoothly. They are also used to create links between different tables.  A foreign key establishes an indexed path to access from one table to another, therefore it IS a key.  It is also a relationship.  What definition do you use for key?

Comment: An FK is a little bit special in that it is also a cross table constraint, but that doesn't make it any less a key, even if it isn't a key to the record it is on.  It is a key to the parent table.