# Is it possible to reference a primary key in one table as a foreign key constraint across more than 2 tables?

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am currently making a database back end system on an airport, using sql through the phpmyadmin server. The criteria is not meant to be perfect but one of the ideas behind the queries is to imagine that either a customer or flight dispatch officer might be looking at the tables. I was wondering if it was possible to reference a primary key as a foreign key across 2 or more tables. In the example below, I want to reference the model number as a foreign key in the bottom 2 tables. I have ensured that the type and character count are the same.

```
    CREATE TABLE Aircraft_Model
    (Model_Number varchar (12) NOT NULL,
    seat_capacity int (3),
    CONSTRAINT pk7 primary key (Model_Number));

    CREATE TABLE Licence_type
    (Rank varchar (25) NOT NULL,
    Model_Number varchar (12),
    CONSTRAINT pk9 primary key (Rank));

    CREATE TABLE Aircraft
    (Aircraft_ID varchar (4) NOT NULL, 
    Model_Number varchar(12),
    airport_base text(13),
    CONSTRAINT pk1 PRIMARY KEY (Aircraft_ID));
```

Is this possible? I only want the database to be able to perform about 12-15 simple queries.

Would the syntax of adding a foreign key be something like this?

```
ALTER TABLE Aircraft
ADD CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY(Model_Number)
REFERENCES Aircraft_Model
```

Does the same foreign key being referenced from a separate table such as Licence_type need a separate constraint to be added or can it be added from the same one with the same fk1 number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if it was possible to reference a primary key as a
>   foreign key across 2 or more tables.

If you mean, "Can two or more tables have foreign keys that reference the same column?", then, yes, you can do that. This seems to be what you mean, but it's *not* what most people mean when they talk about "a foreign key across 2 or more tables".

Declare two different, separate constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE Aircraft
ADD CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY(Model_Number)
REFERENCES Aircraft_Model (Model_Number);

ALTER TABLE License_Type
ADD CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY(Model_Number)
REFERENCES Aircraft_Model (Model_Number);
```

Comment: does this usually have any bearing on the effectiveness of the database? I realise that it may slow it down but it doesn't affect information retrieval I presume? It is still possible to do joins or to use select commands to check who might be available to fly on a certain date?

Comment: Foreign keys enforce *correctness*. Foreign keys make some inserts and updates slower than they might be without foreign keys, but only at the risk of introducing bad data. (The index backing the foreign keys has to be updated.) The change in speed is unnoticeable to humans. They don't affect SELECT statement performance, unless the index backing the foreign key happens to be useful. Any query that's possible without a foreign key constraint is possible with one. (Assuming the absence of such constraints hasn't butchered your data.)

Comment: I haven't run any queries yet, I wanted the constraints to be as correct as possible. in 2 tables, "no fly list" and "passengers", I have the passport number as primary key for both. it is also a foreign key in "reservation". I have marked it as foreign key for just "reservation" and "no fly list"-is this right or does it need to be referenced as foreign key on all three, whether it is primary or not?  I was wondering what to do if a key is not primary but is in 2 tables-i have airport base in the "aircraft" table and the "crew" table but it is primary in none. does it need 2 constraints?

Comment: A FK constraint goes from one table's set of columns to a set of *unique* columns in another. They have to be declared PK or UNIQUE. It constrains each value for the column set in the first table to be a value for the column set in the other. Whenever that is the case, declare the FK. If you're unsure then post another question. Re your post's final question see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24317478).