# Functional Depedency with primary key and unique attribute

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies

So imagine I have a relation like this:

r(A, B, C, D, E)

Where A is the primary key and C is unique. I'm having doubts on how the functional depedencies work, I know since A is the primary key every other attribute depends on it but I don't know what to do with the unique attribute. Does it work the same way as the primary key? Does C depend on A (A-->C)?

I've also seen another case where I have a relation like the one above but with a unique signature with two attributes on it, like this:

unique(C, D)

And I also don't know the meaning of a unique with two attributes instead of a unique declaration for each attribute and how it will affect the functional depedencies.

Thank you for your time and for your responses in advance.

Comment: Hi. What are the definitions of FD & CK? Please don't expect us to quote those--which we must to answer--when you're not willing. What do you find applying them to your situation? What is your textbook/manual/documentation name & edition? What does it say the "unique(C, D)" means? Please don't ask us to write yet another presentation; ask 1 question re the 1st place you are stuck understanding or applying the authoritative presentation you already have. Ask only 1 question. See [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS PKs are irrelevant, CKs matter.

Answer (score -1):

There are many keys -
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951052/differences-between-key-superkey-minimal-superkey-candidate-key-and-primary-k/15365182)

[image]

---

In your case you have A, as primary key, so B,C,D,E are related with A.

Here is [chapter about SK (super-keys)](https://web.csulb.edu/colleges/coe/cecs/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=keys.php)

Comment: I think I get it... but still don't get how this will affect the functional dependencies... basically this is a test question where they give this relation and ask me to write all the functional depedencies, my doubt is if C depends of A, and if there any attributes that depend on the unique attribute C

Comment: I think Philip and Walter give you more professionally answer, deduction tells me that C depends on A, because A is the primary key.

Comment: Not "secondary key", alternate key. An alternate key is a CK so is a superkey & unique. You seem to be confusing relational constraint notions with implementation indexing notions. PS This post really does not answer or explain any of the question post questions.

Comment: should i delete ? Can you explain about difference between constraint notions and implementation indexing notions?

Comment: If you don't understand the terms I used then since they are so basic you really need to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens of published academic information modeling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.)

Comment: ok thank's- i found oracle material which i intend to read and deepen in this field.

Comment: @philipxy Asking for off-site resources is only off-topic in top level questions. I'm pretty sure it's fine in the comment section.

Comment: @mypetlion Sure. I only mentioned that re not asking to preempt the asker posting such a question. PS Comments are not for asking questions that should be question posts, and they are meant for clarifications & criticisms of posts, but of course we can use them for a quick informal ephemeral exchange.

Answer (score -1):

In the design phase, columns A and C would be identified as **Candidate** keys. (Note that there could be more than two.) One would then be selected as the Primary key, and the other(s) would be defined with unique constraints.

Lots of fussy details may come up with NULL (PKs can't be nullable), performance/suitability as foreign keys (factor into capacity planning), and impact on possible business rules.

Comment: This post does not give the asker any justification or explanation or anything that they could apply to any other case. It doesn't address the confusion, vagueness or answers of any of their questions. It's just some statements with some vague connections to the question post.